# Linq to XML query only returning first record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following query, which is only returning the first record.  How can I modify it to return all elements in that category?

CODE:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/Content/xml/Collections.xml"));
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Category")
             .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "Apartment")
             .Select(x => x.Element("ListingId"));
```

XML:

```
       <Items>
         <Category name="Apartment">
           <ListingId>1100121</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100089</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100090</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100092</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100067</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100136</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100302</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100248</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100072</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100167</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100309</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100023</ListingId>
         </Category>
         <Category name="Single Family">
           <ListingId>1100001</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100002</ListingId>
           <ListingId>1100017</ListingId>
         </Category>
       </Items>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Elements` instead of `Element` to get all the matching elements rather than just the first one.

If you're only interested in a single category then you can use this to get all the `ListingId` elements for it.

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Category")
         .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Apartment")
         ?.Elements("ListingId");
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<XElement>` containing all the `ListingId` elements for the Apartment category.

Otherwise if you want to get all `ListingId`s from all matching categories you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Category")
         .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Apartment")
         .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("ListingId"));
```

Comment: How can I get it to return just the value of that node? I changed to elements and it is returning a list of <ListingId>1100121</ListingId> instead of just a list of 1100121

Comment: For a single element you can use `Element.Value` to get the value of the element.

Comment: Can't add .Value once you change to Elements

Comment: For mulitple elements `result.Select(e => e.Value)`